# Authentication mechanism for a web services based application

Tags: authentication, service, web

Authentication mechanism

We are designing a “messaging gateway” so that any email, tweet, short message, etc that needs to be sent by a person and/or application is done through this gateway.

One of the important things we are considering in this design phase is authentication because we think the traditional  pair is not enough to satisfy the future needs of the whole application. I’ve been searching and the “tokens” that facebook uses seem to be involved in the nowadays authentication.

What is, in your opinion, the best way to handle authentication in a web services based provider?

Thanks in advance,

Best Regards,
Wilmer

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Are you the consumer of the service ? Or are there third-party consumers ?

If you are the consumer, I would use a simple HTTP authentification.

If there are third party consumers, I would generate a token (unique ID) for each consumer, and require every consumer to add this token to their request. Then check in my DB that the token does exist. In this way, you can create "accounts", limits, etc. and even blacklist consumers as you wish.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Initially our own apps would be the consumer of the Web Services. Eventually, third parties apps would request services through the gateway. The question, for the last case is, should we have another WebService that returns the token given the <login, password> pair?

Comment: Why don't you keep things simple and just generate a random unique ID (like 32-digit hex) for each consumer, and ask consumers to send this token with each request ? Why do you need login/passwords ? (Or I didn't understand your problem well)